# How to read a file passed from CMD and use this files location from java call?

Tags: java, file, batch-file, input, cmd

I am creating a project that is run by a .bat file. This Java program needs to read in a txt file from within the same directory or a specific directory. But the name of the txt file is passed when running the bat file

Example.. java class in located on my desktop, how would i get a txt file that is also on desktop but i dont know which txt file it is until the name of the file is passed in the CMD..

I no this is a little confusingly explained, but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pass the name of the file as a paramter in `args[]`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      File file = new File(args[0]);
      System.out.println("My file is " + file.getPath());
    }
  }

}
```